# How I make an ImageView show-up immediatlly

Tags: android, eclipse, image, button, imageview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   ImageView img;
   MediaPlayer failure;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      Button bButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.blueBtn);
      img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
      img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      failure= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.failure_sound);

      bButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            failure.start();

        }
       });

      }
```

well thats my code.
I just want to make that when I press the button it'll show the image
then wait 1000 miliseconds, and then make a sound.
BUT(!) unfortunaltly when I press that button: the process waits 1000 ms, and then make the sound and shows the img.

help plz!!!

Comment: Use `Handler` instead of `Thread.sleep`

Comment: and what if I want to show the image, and then delay the whole program, and then to continue and make the sound. (im asking ofcourse because i have that kund of issue...)

Comment: can please someone help me here. i want something that dose the same effect as sleep without freezing my UI. the hendler doesnt make my program stop. i want to stop the program in the midle of a for loop, display a picture, and then to stop everything (the loop). but the handler dont do that. best regrads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your onClick handler:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);            
    v.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
       public void run() {  failure.start(); }
    },1000);
}
```

Comment: and what if I want to show the image, and then delay the whole program, and then to continue and make the sound.
(im asking ofcourse because i have that kund of issue...)

Comment: What do you mean - delay the whole program? You want to prevent user interacting with it or you want to delay some code execution?

Comment: im want to do that delay in the midle of a for loop, and now with this postDelayed the loop keep countinuing. and i want everyting to stop for 1000 ms, and only after that to keep countinue the loop.
thank you veryyy much!!!

Comment: Split the loop in two parts: before delay and after delay. Put the first part before v.postDelayed() call. Put the second part right after failure.start() call.

Comment: unfotunatly it dosent help.
the loop continues!
ohhhhhh im sitting hoursssss on this :(

Comment: can please someone help me here. i want something that dose the same effect as sleep without freezing my UI. the hendler doesnt make my program stop. i want to stop the program in the midle of a for loop, display a picture, and then to stop everything (the loop). but the handler dont do that. best regrads

Answer (score 0):

With `Thread.sleep(10000);` you are causing the main thread to freeze and thus the UI cannot be updated for that amount of time.

If you want to wait for a certain amount of time to do something, you may use a `Handler` instead, so the UI can be updated in the meantime:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             failure.start();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: and what if I want to show the image, and then delay the whole program, and then to continue and make the sound. (im asking ofcourse because i have that kind of issue...)

Comment: can please someone help me here. i want something that dose the same effect as sleep without freezing my UI. the hendler doesnt make my program stop. i want to stop the program in the midle of a for loop, display a picture, and then to stop everything (the loop). but the handler dont do that. best regrads

Answer (score 0):

You're putting your UI thread to sleep, which causes your app to freeze and the image not showing up.
A better approach for this is to use a handler, which will execute code after a delay and will not freeze your UI.

A quick adaption of your clickListener would be:

```
bButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);            
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                failure.start();
            }
        }, 1000);
   });
}
```

Comment: and what if I want to show the image, and then delay the whole program, and then to continue and make the sound. (im asking ofcourse because i have that kind of issue...)

Comment: can please someone help me here. i want something that dose the same effect as sleep without freezing my UI. the hendler doesnt make my program stop. i want to stop the program in the midle of a for loop, display a picture, and then to stop everything (the loop). but the handler dont do that. best regrads